# Where did Euripides say "keep a balance in your life"?

Tags: quote-source, greek-language, euripides

I've seen this attributed to Euripides in [various](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/euripides_118847) [places](https://quotefancy.com/quote/1002585/Euripides-The-best-and-safest-thing-is-to-keep-a-balance-in-your-life-acknowledge-the):

> The best and safest thing is to keep a balance in your life, acknowledge the great powers around us and in us. If you can do that, and live that way, you are really a wise person.

I like it but the rendering sounds an awful lot like a self-help book at a grocery story; wondering if anyone knows where it comes from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be from Kenneth Cavander’s translation of Euripides’ [*The Bacchae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bacchae), which was published in 1968 under the title *The Bacchae of Euripides* (University of Nebraska Press). It was performed at Yale University in 1969:

> In the spring of 1969, the Repertory Theatre of the Yale School of Drama mounted a production [of *The Bacchae*] using the Kenneth Cavander translation, directed by André Gregory.
>
> <sub>Karelisa Hartigan (1995). [*Greek Tragedy on the American Stage : Ancient Drama in the Commercial Theater, 1882–1994*, p. 83](https://archive.org/details/greektragedyamer0000unse/page/82/mode/2up). Westport: Greenwood Press.</sub>

A report on the production in *Life* magazine included the quotation:

> In choosing to produce *The Bacchae* at Yale, Dean Robert Brustein says he was inspired by a harrowing photograph of hippies during their recent march on Washington when they confronted troops with bayonets at the Pentagon Building. […]
>
> The timeliness of Euripides’ play extends beyond its theatrical interests into the realm of modern morals. It makes its point in the simplest possible words, spoken by a messenger who is stunned by the Dionysian horrors he has just witnessed: “The best and safest thing is to keep a balance in your life, acknowledge the great powers around us and in us. If you can do that, and live that way, you are a wise man.”
>
> <sub>Tom Prideaux (1969). ‘[A cry from the past for an artistic conscience](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kk8EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA32)’. In *Life* 66:13 (April 4, 1969), pp. 32–34.</sub>

The quotation is a loose translation of the lines below, which follow immediately upon the messenger’s description of Pentheus being ripped apart by his mother Agave and the Bacchantes:

> τὸ σωφρονεῖν δὲ καὶ σέβειν τὰ τῶν θεῶν
> κάλλιστον: οἶμαι δ᾽ αὐτὸ καὶ σοφώτατον
> θνητοῖσιν εἶναι κτῆμα τοῖσι χρωμένοις.
>
> Soundness of mind and reverence for the affairs of the gods is best; and this, I think, is the wisest possession for those mortals who adopt it.
>
> <sub>Euripides. [*The Bacchae* 1150–1152](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0091%3Acard%3D1114). Translated by T. A. Buckley (1850). Perseus Digital Library.</sub>